# Ubercart - how to get order information from order ID?

Tags: 7, ubercart

**How to get an object of `Order` *(or something similar - details of an order!)* by providing order id?** Perhaps, some kind of code like: `$order = order_load($orderId);`

I'm new to Ubercart (3.x)/Drupal (7.x) and searched the title but found no solutions.

I need to create a view/*page by custom module* which displays "My Purchases" or "My Sells"

I need to get complete Order details, by providing order-id. Also need the creator/seller and buyer info of the order.

Can someone give me some PHP example/other ways possibly using a View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Ubercart API at [api.ubercart.me](http://api.ubercart.me), it is

```
$orders = uc_order_load($orderId);
```

`$orders` is an array, so `$order = $orders[0];`

See:
http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_order!uc_order.module/function/uc_order_load/7

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well

```
$result = db_query("SELECT order_id FROM {uc_orders} WHERE order_status 
IN ('abandoned', 'pending') ");
$deleted = 0;
 foreach($result as $row){
   uc_order_delete($row->order_id);
   $deleted++;
 }
drupal_set_message($deleted . ' Abandoned or Pending Orders deleted', 'status');
```